# The logic of the ORM request does not work

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, orm

I wanted to make a request to store the winners of the category model in it. That is, there are several nominations in each category, and category_nomination is attached to MemberNomination (work of user). I have a function that looks for category_nomination winners and it kind of works. But I can't do the same with category. I have the sum of the result__score from each MemberNomination from different EventStaff, but I need to make sure that these result__scores from MemberNomination are summed up, find the member who has the highest score in a certain category!
But my code gives me MemberNomination those with the highest scores of the sum result__score and belong to a certain category.
For example, now he gives me:
1 place
Alexey Volkov
22 points

2nd place
Ghost Face
12 points

3rd place
Ghost Face
11 points

That is, if my code worked correctly, it would give:

1st place
Ghost Face
23 points

2nd place
Alexey Volkov
22 points

3rd place
???
???

That is, the same member has several MemberNomination, but they need to be added together, since they belong to the same category

My models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from django_resized import ResizedImageField


class PlaceChoices(models.IntegerChoices):
    FIRST = 1, 'Первое'
    SECOND = 2, 'Второе'
    THIRD = 3, 'Третье'


class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=10,
                            help_text="Введите название категории",
                            verbose_name="Название категории")

    description = models.TextField(max_length=100,
                                   help_text="Введите описание категории",
                                   verbose_name="Описание категории")

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Категория'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Категории'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Nomination(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50,
                            help_text="Введите название номинации",
                            verbose_name="Название номинации")

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Номинация'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Номинации'
        ordering = ['id']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class NominationAttribute(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    nomination = models.ForeignKey('Nomination', models.PROTECT, related_name='attribute')
    max_score = models.IntegerField(default=5)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Event(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50,
                            help_text='Введите название мероприятия',
                            verbose_name='Название мероприятия')

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Мероприятие'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Мероприятия'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Member(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey('users.User', models.PROTECT)
    event = models.ForeignKey('Event', models.PROTECT)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Участник'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Участники'

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return f"Участник {self.user} в мероприятии {self.event}"


class EventStaff(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey('users.User', models.PROTECT)
    category_nomination = models.ForeignKey('CategoryNomination', models.PROTECT, default=1, related_name='staffs')

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Судья'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Судьи'

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return f"Судья {self.user} в мероприятии {self.category_nomination}"


class EventCategory(models.Model):
    event = models.ForeignKey('Event', models.PROTECT)
    category = models.ForeignKey('Category', models.PROTECT)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Категории мероприятия'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Категории мероприятий'

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return f"{self.event} --- {self.category}"


class CategoryNomination(models.Model):
    event_category = models.ForeignKey('EventCategory', models.PROTECT)
    nomination = models.ForeignKey('Nomination', models.PROTECT, related_name='nom')

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Номинации категорий'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Номинации категорий'

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return f"{self.event_category} --- {self.nomination}"


class MemberNomination(models.Model):
    member = models.ForeignKey('Member', models.PROTECT, related_name='membernom')
    photo_1 = ResizedImageField(size=[500, 300], quality=75, null=True, blank=True)
    photo_2 = ResizedImageField(size=[500, 300], quality=75, null=True, blank=True)
    photo_3 = ResizedImageField(size=[500, 300], quality=75, null=True, blank=True)
    photo_4 = ResizedImageField(size=[500, 300], quality=75, null=True, blank=True)
    category_nomination = models.ForeignKey('CategoryNomination', models.PROTECT, related_name='categ')

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Номинация участника'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Номинации участника'

    @property
    def is_done(self):
        count_referee = self.category_nomination.staffs.count()
        count_results = self.results.count()
        return count_results == count_referee

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return f"{self.member} --- {self.category_nomination}"


class WinnerNomination(models.Model):
    member = models.ForeignKey('Member', models.PROTECT)
    nomination = models.ForeignKey('Nomination', models.PROTECT)
    category = models.ForeignKey('Category', models.PROTECT)
    place = models.IntegerField(choices=PlaceChoices.choices)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Победитель номинации'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Победители номинации'


class WinnerCategory(models.Model):
    member = models.ForeignKey('Member', models.PROTECT)
    category = models.ForeignKey('Category', models.PROTECT)
    place = models.IntegerField(choices=PlaceChoices.choices)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Гран-при'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Гран-при'


class Result(models.Model):
    membernomination = models.ForeignKey('MemberNomination', models.PROTECT, related_name='results')
    score = models.IntegerField()
    eventstaff = models.ForeignKey('EventStaff', models.PROTECT)
    score_retail = models.JSONField(default=None, null=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Оценка'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Оценки'

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return f"{self.score} --- {self.membernomination}"
```

My views.py:

```
class ResultOfAllEvents(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'events/end_result.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        data = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)

        win_nominations = {}
        nominations = CategoryNomination.objects.all()

        for nomination in nominations:
            member_nominations = MemberNomination.objects.filter(category_nomination=nomination)

            top_three = member_nominations.annotate(total_score=Sum('results__score')).order_by('-total_score')[:3]
            win_nominations[nomination] = top_three

        data['win_nominations'] = win_nominations


# PROBLEM PART CODE --->>>>>>
        win_categories = {}
        categories = Category.objects.all()

        for category in categories:
            member_nominations = MemberNomination.objects.filter(category_nomination__event_category__category=category)

            top_three = member_nominations.annotate(total_score=Sum('results__score')).order_by('-total_score')[:3]
            win_categories[category] = top_three

        data['win_categories'] = win_categories

        return data
```

My html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
{% load static %}
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/normilize.css' %}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/style.css' %}">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@500;900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
    <title>Конечный результат</title>
</head>

<body>
<main class="main">
    <div class="container">
        <ul class="masters-list winners-list">
            <h3 class="pink-title">Winners of category_nomination:</h3>
            {% for nomination, member_nominations in win_nominations.items %}

                <h3 class="pink-title">{{ nomination.nomination.name }}</h3>

                {% for member_nomination in member_nominations %}

                <li class="master winner">
                    <h2>{{ forloop.counter }} place</h2>

                    <p class="winner-name">
                    {{ member_nomination.member.user.first_name }}
                    {{ member_nomination.member.user.last_name }}
                    </p>
                    <span class="winner-balls"> {{ member_nomination.total_score }} balls</span>
                </li>

                {% endfor %}

            {% endfor %}
        </ul>

        <h3 class="pink-title" style="border: 0">Winners of category</h3>

        <ul class="masters-list winners-list">
            {% for category, member_nominations in win_categories.items %}

                <h3 class="pink-title">{{ category.name }}</h3>

                {% for member_nomination in member_nominations %}

                <li class="master winner">
                    <h2>{{ forloop.counter }} place</h2>

                    <p class="winner-name">
                    {{ member_nomination.member.user.first_name }}
                    {{ member_nomination.member.user.last_name }}
                    </p>
                    <span class="winner-balls"> {{ member_nomination.total_score }} balls</span>
                </li>

                {% endfor %}

            {% endfor %}
        </ul>

    </div>
</main>
</body>
</html>
```

I've been talking to ChatGPT a lot...